# Can you get a union of all the subtypes of a base type?

Tags: typescript

I don't know if this is possible in typescript but I would like to be able to do something like below:

```
interface Animal {
  speed: number,
}

interface WingedAnimal extends Animal {
  wingspan: number
}

interface Mammal extends Animal {
  gestationPeriod: number
}

type SubtypesUnion<T> = //some definition

const animalProps: SubtypesUnion<Animal> // gives you WingedAnimal | Mammal
```

The idea being that if there were 100 subtypes of Animal it would be a union of all of them. In practice I would like to do something like below:

```
interface Order {
  material: Material,
  destination: Destination,   
}

interface Material {
  name: string
  description: string
}

interface Gears extends Material {
  axiesConfiguration: 'Parallel' | 'Intersecting'
}

interface Spanners extends Material {
  size: number
}

interface Destination {
  address: string
}

interface CorsBorder extends Destination {
  customsFees: number
}

interface Local extends Destination {
  customerPickup: boolean
}

type FieldConfig<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { visible?: boolean} &  {props?: FieldConfig<T[K]> }
} 

const orderFormConfigForEdit: FieldConfig<Order> = {
  material: {
    visible: true,
    props: {
      description: {
        visible: false,
      },
      name: {
        visible: true,
      }
      axiesConfiguration: {
        visible: true
      }
    }
  },
  destination: {
    visible: true,
    props: {
      address: {
        visible: false
      }
      customsFees: {
        visible: true
      }
      customerPickup: {
        visible: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that with the current `FieldConfig` definition `axiesConfiguration`, `customsFees` and `customerPickup` would not be allowed. Because they belong to subtypes of `Material` and `Destination` respectively. So I imagined somethings like

```
type FieldConfig<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { visible?: boolean} &  {props?: FieldConfig<SubtypesUnion<T[K]>> }
}
```

With the definition of `SubtypesUnion` eluding me or maybe it's not possible. `Order` is a domain object that gets used for other purposes as well.

Comment: Why not use... `Animal`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because I want to map a type from animal recursively that has all its properties and the properties of its children. Well a more complex business object.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to give some context about the actual problem being solved?

Comment: Ok, will try make it more detailed.

Comment: @MarthinusEngelbrecht There isn't a way to do it automatically. You could do something like have an interface `DestinationSubtypes` to which you add members every time you define a new subtype. This would avoid manually creating a huge union with all subtypes in one place .. but would ultimately still be a manual process

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks, yeah also thought about it. Problem is that I would then have to also declare something like `OrderWithSubtypes` and repeat the whole nested structure setting the `destination` property to type `DestinationSubtypes` and in actual fact the structure is quite deep.

Answer (score 0):

Was this you were looking for [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkBnABwggBMAuZEAV0wCNoAaQgX0MNEixEKAOqgA5rXRZcyCAA9IIGmTQZseIqWQB3CZTggGzNtB58B0eEmQBZOJg1zFEZaulOtpSWTBwwwAD2IAAK0EH0jCzsUOaEYACeVMgAykysiVRkAKoYwQA8ACrOSipqMngAPshiIJI0HrgAfMgAvOVO1bX1jTgA3HwIwb7IhhUhUIEUZAxpGUkQOXkg%20b0t7V4klNSRAMw8QA)

```
interface Animal {
  speed: number,
}

interface WingedAnimal extends Animal {
    wingspan: number
}

interface Mammal extends Animal {
    gestationPeriod: number
}

type SubtypesUnion<T extends Animal | WingedAnimal> = Animal | WingedAnimal;

const animalProps: SubtypesUnion<Animal> = {
    speed: 3
}
```